# Pinescript short position not closing

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

[code extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF62p.png)

The code is shown in the picture above. It is only opening one position as shown in the second picture
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3ico.png)

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Instead, copy and paste it here and use the code blocks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You `sellCondition` can never be `true` because you have `strategy.position_size > 0` there.

`strategy.position_size` can only be `true` if you are in a long position.

You should be checking `strategy.position_size < 0` instead.

Comment: apologies for the picture I couldn't get the code to format